# Sort CMap Key by String Length

Tags: c++, mfc, stl

Previously, I am using STL map to perform the mentioned task.

```
struct ltstr
{
    bool operator()(std::string s1, std::string s2) const
    {
      const int l1 = s1.length();
      const int l2 = s2.length();
      if (l1 == l2) {
          // In alphabetical order.
          return s1.compare(s2) < 0;
      }
      // From longest length to shortest length.
      return l1 > l2;
    }
};
std::map<std::string, int, ltstr> m;
```

How can I perform the same task using CMap?

```
// How to make key sorted by string length?
CMap<CString, LPCTSTR, int, int> m;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `CMap` is actually a hash map, and therefore provides no ordering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot.  From [the MSDN documentation for `CMap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s897094z.aspx):

> You might think that this iteration is sequential by key value; it is not.  The sequence of retrieved elements is indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence in a map is determined by the hashing value, and is for all intents and purposes... *random*.

Instead, you may want to keep/generate a sorted list of pointers to the keys or something like that.